# Is there a way to seperate cli --filters arguments onto seperate line like it in bash?

Tags: amazon-web-services

For example in bash you can do:

```
echo hello \
world

$ hello world
```

Is there a way to do that for long --filters when using the AWS CLI?

For example, the following command is quite long and can become bloated when doing complex filtering/lookups:

```
aws ssm get-inventory --filters "Key=AWS:InstanceInformation.PlatformName,Values=Ubuntu,Type=Equal" "Key=AWS:InstanceInformation.InstanceStatus,Values=Active,Type=Equal"
```

It would be better if you could do:

```
aws ssm get-inventory --filters "Key=AWS:InstanceInformation.PlatformName,Values=Ubuntu,Type=Equal" \
"Key=AWS:InstanceInformation.InstanceStatus,Values=Active,Type=Equal"
```

But I keep getting parsing errors when trying this.

Comment: Options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46808582/271415 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/7316194/271415

Comment: Thanks, the second link option worked nicely:


aws ssm get-inventory --filters "Key=AWS:InstanceInformation.PlatformName,Values=Ubuntu,Type=Equal" \
"Key=AWS:InstanceInformation.ComputerName,Values=example,Type=BeginWith" \